# spotify mobile app tracking without SDK?

Tags: sdk

Is there anyway to track conversions and have them correctly attributed on a mobile app if the app (developed by spotify) has no SDK tracking? Want to track on both iOS and Android.

If you require more details - please advise. Are there any ways to surpass this; a customisable solution or a suggested product?

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile measurement and attribution companies use SDK tracking. Only a few companies offer a server-to-server alternative, but it should be noted that it is generally limited in scope and not as accurate as using the SDK option. You should look to outreach directly to the companies - I haven't dealt with them all and so from personal experience, I can only recommend AppsFlyer.